# Getitem vs Iter & Next. What should be used when?

Tags: python, iterator, containers, iterable

I have been learning python. One of the questions i have is whether I should use `getitem` or `iter` & `next` to make iterable classes in Python.

`iter` & `next` seems more sensible to me, but that leaves the question when should we use `getitem` then. Also I think I read somewhere that `iter` and `next` will be deprecated and `getitem` would only be supported in future python releases. And how can slices be supported using `iter` and `next` (haven't found much material on that).

And in what cases would one be better to use than the other?

Comment: Where did you read that? No, iterables (`__iter__` and `next()`) are **not** going to be deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__iter__()` and `next()` (`__next__()` in Python 3) to define an *iterator*. If you just want it to be an *iterable*, `__iter__()` suffices (and must return an iterator). See the [*Iterator Types* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter).

To support legacy *ordered* containers, the `iter()` function will also accept an object that implements both `__len__` and `__getitem__`; these are documented under [*Emulating container types*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types). You can't implement an *iterator* with those methods however; a call to `iter()` will produce an object that is an iterator that then uses those methods to access the items in the container in sequence.

Not all iterables are ordered containers, for example (the `set` and `dict` types being prime examples). Such types can be iterated over (yielding results in a implementation-dependent order you should not rely on), but you can't *index* each item as they are not stored at a specific point in the container.

Both protocols are here to stay, neither one is deprecated.

Comment: Okay, i think I understand a bit now. Maybe my question was just what is a Container vs Iterator. A class may be both a container and iterator generally, like lists. But some may not be iterable like sets? something along the lines,right?

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri: sets are iterable too; they are not *ordered*. So they don't have a `__getitem__` method.

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri: so you can have a container that is not ordered and so doesn't support retrieving values by index. But they *are* iterable, which means they'll produce values in 'arbitrary' (implementation dependent) order.